# Minimum number of points for maximum distance in n dimensions

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Given an n-dimensional unit cube ([0, 1]^n), how would I determine the minimum number of points needed, so that I could distribute the points inside the cube and the distance between any other (not chosen) point inside the cube and the closest placed point is at most a given distance d?
And how would one place these points?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are asking for covering a cube by congruent spheres.
Let me try to translate down to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Let $S$ be a unit square in the plane. Define $r_\min(k)$ as the minimum
radius $r$ such that $k$ disks of radius $r$ can be placed to cover $S$
completely. Under such a placement,

> the distance between any other (not chosen) point inside the cube and the closest placed point is at most a given distance $r$

because it falls within a disk of radius $r$
(where I have changed the OP's $d$ to $r$, for **r**adius).

So, for example, an optimal placement of $7$ points in a square
is as shown below:

---

[image: 7DisksSquare]

  

<sup>Nurmela, Kari J., and Patric RJ Östergård. "Covering a square with up to 30 equal circles." (2000).</sup>


 

<sup>[CiteSeer link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.30.3894).</sup>

---

There is a complex literature on these problems, which have considerable
practical significance, e.g.,

> Huang, Chi-Fu, Yu-Chee Tseng, and Li-Chu Lo. "The coverage problem in three-dimensional wireless sensor networks." *Global Telecommunications Conference*, 2004. GLOBECOM'04. IEEE. Vol. 5. IEEE, 2004.